# domain of flow of an inner vector field is a manifold with corners

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $X$ be a manifold with corners. Let $\vec v$ be an inner vector field on $X$. The existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE says there's a domain of flow $\mathfrak D(\vec v)\subset \mathbb R\times X$ containing $\left\{ 0 \right\} \times X$, $[0,\varepsilon_x)\times \left\{ x \right\} $ for each $x\in \partial X$ and $(-a_x,b_x)\times \left\{ x \right\}$ for $x\in X\setminus \partial X$.

**Question 1.** Is the domain of flow $\mathfrak D(\vec v)\subset \mathbb R\times X$ an embedded submanifold with corners?

**Question 2.** For each $x\in X$, does $(0,x)\in \mathfrak D(\vec v)$ have a product neighborhood $[0,\varepsilon _x)\times U_x\subset \mathfrak D(\vec v)$ with $U_x\subset X$ open?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I will remove my comment.

Comment: What do you want "the" domain of flow $\mathfrak{D}(\vec{v})$ to be? I think that the answer depends on whether you want to require that for each $x \in X$ the set $\mathfrak{D}_x(\vec{v}) := \{ t \in \mathbb{R} \, | \, (t,x) \in \mathfrak{D}(\vec{v}) \}$ to be the maximally connected interval around $0$ for which there exists an integral curve of $\vec{v}$ passing through $x$ at $0$ (so for example $\mathfrak{D}_x(\vec{v})$ can be a two-sided interval such as $(-\infty,\infty)$ where $x$ is a corner point) or only to look at intervals which lie in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ for corner points.

Comment: Dear @levap, sorry for the vague formulation. I mean the second interpretation, as in the third-to-last paragraph of section 4.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306078.pdf). Indeed my "next" question is how to prove the smoothness assertion there.

Comment: @Arrow: Under the interpretation you write in the question, the domain of the flow won't be a manifold with corners as simple examples demonstrate (think about $x \frac{d}{dx}$ on $[0,\infty)$). However, the paper talks about a semiflow which usually means that you are allowing points (even interior ones) to flow only for non-negative time. I think that in this case the domain of the flow will be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times X$ and in particular, a manifold with corners. This can be proved when $\vec{v}$ is strictly inner by mimicking the usual argument but when $\vec{v}$ is

Comment: merely inner, it seems more subtle. Even the statement "the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE says that there's a domain of flow containing $[0,\varepsilon_{x}) \times \{x\}$ for $x \in \partial X$" does not seem completely trivial. I thought about it a little but am not sure how to fill all the details.

Comment: Dear @levap, for me, by definition a vector field on a sector is the restriction of a vector field on an open subset of Euclidean space containing it. Applying the ODE theorem to the "extension" and using the fact the restriction to the sector is inner seems to give the result regarding $[0,\varepsilon_{x}) \times \{x\}$ for $x \in \partial X$. Am I missing something?